# in SQL, how to cursor-paginate through rows that are ordered by a column that can have duplicate values?

Tags: sql, pagination

I am trying to cursor-paginate through rows where the order-by column has duplicate values, and I am having issues with finding a way to "slice" the dataset in the middle of those duplicate values.

My (Postgres) schema is

```
create table posts
(
    id    uuid         not null primary key,
    title varchar(255) not null
);
create table comments
(
    id      uuid not null primary key,
    post_id uuid not null references posts
);
```

My current approach is to first query posts ordered by their comment count:

```
select 
  "posts".*, 
  count("comments"."id") as "comments_count"
from "posts"
left join "comments" on "posts"."id" = "comments"."post_id"
group by "posts"."id"
order by "comments_count" desc
```

Then page through that dataset via where and limit:

```
with "cte" as (
    {....the query from above....}
)
select *
from "cte"
where "comments_count" <= (select "comments_count" from "cte" where "id" = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003')
limit 3;
```

The problem is when two rows have the same comment count.

For example, the CTE (without the outer query) returns the below rows, where rows of id `...0003` and `...0002` both have `comment_count` of 2.

The problem occurs when I try to query for rows of uuid `...0002`, `...0006`, and `...0007`

| id | creation_timestamp | comments_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000004 | 2023-07-10 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 5 |
| 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 2020-07-06 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 4 |
| 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003 | 2023-07-09 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 2 |
| 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002 | 2023-07-08 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 2 |
| 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000006 | 2023-07-12 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 1 |
| 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000007 | 2023-07-13 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 0 |
| 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001 | 2023-07-07 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 0 |
| 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000005 | 2023-07-11 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 0 |

In the outer `where` clause (`where "comments_count" <=`) trying both <= and <

- with `<=`, it returns `...0003`, `...0002`, `...0006`
- with `<`, it return `...0006`, `...0007`, `...0001`

I don't want to use offset-based pagination. I am thinking I might have to entirely restructure my query, but I hope not. What should I try?

Answer (score 1):

One solution I have found is to make a counts-column that is unique via concatenating it with the id.

```sql
with "cte" as (
    select
        "posts".*,
        count("comments"."id") as comments_count,
        concat(count("comments"."id"), ':', "posts".id) as comments_count_id
    from "posts"
             left join "comments" on "posts"."id" = "comments"."post_id"
    group by "posts"."id"
    order by "comments_count_id" desc
)
select *
from "cte"
where "comments_count_id" < (select "comments_count_id" from "cte" where "id" = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003')
limit 3;
```

Performance at scale might be a concern, though